# Using SVN, how do I "move" commits from the dev branch to a feature branch?

Tags: svn

So here's my situation. A developer started a feature on the main development branch. Now we need to move them to a feature branch. Okay, fine. Create a branch, merge those changes. But now I want to REMOVE these changes from the main development branch.

If I revert or "reverse-merge" these changes off the main development branch, how can the feature branch merge in bug fixes from the main development branch without merging in all these "reverse-merges"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "move" a commit because a revision is a record of changes to the whole repository made at that point in time.

What I would suggest is:

1. Merge the changes from the dev branch to the feature branch
2. Reverse-merge the changes on the dev branch.
3. If you have to merge bug fixes from the dev branch to the feature branch, **only** do it with revisions that are outside the range where the reverse merge happened.
4. When the developer is done with his work, merge the changes from the feature branch back to the dev branch.

Comment: I need to do something that's conceptually like moving, so that's why I phrased it that way. But anyway, your soluction makes merging bug fixes slightly more complicated, but the re-integration shouldn't be affected at all. Is that right?

Comment: I've done similar (but on a smaller scale) and it's been fine.